# Why does my UPDATE using a CTE affect all rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a task table with 1000 rows in my Postgres 12 database. I need to get last 100 rows non-executed, set column `executed` to 1 and return that selected rows. If I do code below, it updates all 1000 rows. Like it does not see `LIMIT`. It seems that's why this query with 100k rows executed took seconds! What is my mistake?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, executed
    FROM task
    WHERE executed=0
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 100
)
UPDATE task t
SET executed=1
FROM cte
RETURNING t.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the relation between the two parts of the query, in the WHERE condition for the UPDATE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, executed
    FROM task
    WHERE executed=0
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 100
)
UPDATE task
SET executed=1
FROM cte
WHERE cte.id = task.id -- This one
RETURNING t.id
```